# Configuring Solr Cloud

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I've installed solr and zookeeper in two different machines, and have edited zoo.cfg file as instructed on solr wiki, zookeeper was launched and connected successfully, but when i try to ingest data on one machine, it does not reflect on other machine, indexed file should go in zookeeper data folder, but it is getting stored in solr data folder.
Can anyone help over this, or give me steps  from scratch on how to configure it and check if it is working.

Comment: indexed file should go in zookeeper data folder.! No it won't. it will store data about the cluster. not indexed data.

Comment: still, i have no idea how to make it work, solr cloud, no help from the articles i referred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right after the solrCloud setup with zookeeper, I was trying to copy my collection from stand-alone solr,but DIH was not reflecting, 
Then I copied an example DIH named db from solr/example dir. and made changes to it according to my connection and query, and pasted it in configsets dir and placed necessary jars in lib. Also, node name has to be same on both the machines. It's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

1. you should have zookeeper ensemble setup, as you mentioned you have it
2. you should setup solr cluster using multiple machines.
3. once solrcloud setup is done you should start solr with zookeeper ensebmle using param -z (ex: `bin/solr start -z zookeepermachineIP:2181`)

Everything is well explained in detail [Here](http://blog.thedigitalgroup.com/susheelk/2015/08/03/solrcloud-2-nodes-solr-1-node-zk-setup/). also refer [Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble) to setup a ZooKeeper Ensemble

Comment: when i run the command 'http://<Node1IP>:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name<myCollection>&numShards=2&replicationFactor=2&maxShardsPerNode=2&collection.configName=renametoyourname_configs with my configurations, it returns the error 'Error CREATEing SolrCore 'play_shard1_replica1': Unable to create core [play_shard1_replica1] Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler' and the same conf is working properly on standalone solr
I can't understand what could be the possible issue. it doesnt show any core, can u tell me what all DIH conf do i need to do